# Setting System Permission before OnCreate

Tags: android

How can I set system permission of reading and writing external storage even before OnCreate of an activity. So only after user set this permission programmatically, the applications start screen should be shown.

Comment: Request the permission in a previous activity, before starting this one.

Answer (score 1):

I see these 3 options:

- Create a SplashScreen activity which only exist to require these
     permissions at the first boot
- Or, In your activity make a perm request and go on only if the user
            grant these permissions
- Or, (not sure if it works) Since `onStart()` is called just after
            `onCreate()` you can try to make the perm request in the `onStart()`
            and initialize your attributes and everything in the `onCreate()`

**PS:** You can also use [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) library which really simplifies the process to request permissions to the user

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Marshmallow, you just declare it in your manifest. On Marshmallow and later, you can't. You have to check and request before using an API which requires the permission, so you will have already run (or while running) your `onCreate()`.

Comment: You mean Marshmallow I guess